# Echo a title or a custom field with PyroCMS

Tags: pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

What I trying to do is to echo the title if a custom field is empty.

```
{{ if custom_fields:alternative_title != "" }}
    {{ custom_fields }}{{ alternative_title }}{{ /custom_fields }}
{{ else }}
    {{ title }}
{{ endif }}
```

This code didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What's in `custom_fields:alternative_title`? This is an array?

Comment: A field value. But using {{ custom_fields:alternative_title }} doesn't work.